# How to substitute/run curl with every variable in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have setup this code for myself.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$ipaddress = array("8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1", "8.8.4.4");
foreach ($ipaddress as $key => $val) {
$url="https://example.com/test/check?ip=$val"; //
print_r(get_data($url)); //dumps the content, you can manipulate as you wish to
/* gets the data from a URL */

function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$word = 'active';
// Test if string contains the word 
if(strpos($data, $word) !== false){
    echo "Word Found!";
} else{
    echo "Word Not Found!";
}
}
}
?>
```

However for some reason (read my incapability), the value for $val is only 8.8.8.8, i want to substitute each IP in the array at the end of $url till i get echo "Word Found!".

I am stuck with the part $val, once i solve that, i can perhaps setup if/else command?

Can anyone help me with completing this code?

Comment: Why do you define `function get_data` in a loop?

Comment: I need to check each and every $val page for the word active.

Comment: And defining funciton __once__ outside the loop is not an option?

Comment: You do that by calling `print_r(get_data($url));`, no need to define the function itself that often. Move the function definition out of that loop to after `error_reporting(E_ALL);` You wouldn't even need to make it a function

Comment: @kerbh0lz so should i move `function get_data ($url)` to before the `$ipaddress`? wouldn't it miss `$url`?

Comment: Yes. No, you wouldn't, since you give `$url` as a parameter to your function. And `print_r(get_data($url));` could be just `get_data($url);` since your function already `echo`s its result

Comment: @kerbh0lz i have set it up as this - https://3v4l.org/BXnAe but it still wont run (white page only, and wont echo too)

Comment: Naah, move the whole function, like https://3v4l.org/iJvGS

Comment: @kerbh0lz, thanks for that, however i do not think this will work for me, as i want to split the one what says Word found and put it in an array.

Comment: Last comment, that would need some more alterations, see if https://3v4l.org/ocWYG works for you, if it does I'll make it an answer with more detailed comments if you want

Comment: That WORKS :D however can you please make it an answer and explain it more, because i am trying to add it into my main code, and an explanation would help a lot :D

Comment: Sorry for posting so late, you didn't tag me and I just now realized you commented. Glad it works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working code. I renamed the function to something more meaningful and added the url to check inside the function. Note, you only need to declare the function once.

The function `checkActiveIp()` will now return `true` (if `active` was found in the response) or `false` if it wasn't. `if ( checkActiveIp($ip) ) {...` will call the function and check for the result and if the function returns `true`, will push the checked IP to the end of the array `$activeIps` using [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

In the end, the array `$activeIps` will contain all IPs whose response contains the word `active`.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function checkActiveIp($ip) {
    $url = "https://example.com/test/check?ip=$ip";
    $timeout = 5;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $word = 'active';
    // Test if string contains the word 
    if(strpos($data, $word) !== false){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


$activeIps = array();
$ips = array("8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1", "8.8.4.4");
foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    if ( checkActiveIp($ip) ) {
        array_push($activeIps, $ip);
    }
}

print_r($activeIps);
```